# how to run bpy callback on workspace tools change

Tags: event-handling, workspace, bpy

How to add a pre-draw hook to current context workspace.tools change?

I attempted to get there using `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(...)` which as it runs on every draw, checks if workspace.tools changed, and if it changed, run my callback, but my callback wants to add its own `SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add` and doing it this way adds it a frame-too-late, leaving the view port undrawn until a user event repaints the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post online
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/update-property-when-active-tool-changes/11467/12

summary: maybe there is a mainline callback new
https://developer.blender.org/D10635

> AFWS Jan '20
>
> @kaio
>
> This seem like a better solution. It’s kind of a mystery code, cause I
> couldn’t figure out where you got that code info ,but then started
> looking at the space_toolsystem_common.py file. kaio AFWS Jan '20
>
> Just realized there might be a cleaner way of getting callbacks for
> active tools using the msgbus. Since workspace tools aren’t rna
> properties themselves, figured it’s possible to monitor the
> bpy_prop_collection which changes with the tool.
>
> The handle is the workspace itself, so shouldn’t have to worry about
> keeping a reference. The subscription lasts until a new file is
> loaded, so add a load_post callback which reapplies it.
>
> Note this doesn’t proactively subscribe to workspaces added
> afterwards. Might need a separate callback for that :joy:
>
> ```
> import bpy
>
> def rna_callback(workspace):
>     idname = workspace.tools[-1].idname
>     print(idname)
>
> def subscribe(workspace):
>     bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
>         key=ws.path_resolve("tools", False),
>         owner=workspace,
>         args=(workspace,),
>         notify=rna_callback)
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     ws = bpy.context.workspace
>     subscribe(bpy.context.workspace)
>
> # Subscribe to all workspaces: if 0:
>     for ws in bpy.data.workspaces:
>         subscribe(bpy.context.workspace)
>
> # Clear all workspace subscriptions if 0:
>     for ws in bpy.data.workspaces:
>         bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(ws)
> ```